# Google Maps Embed in Unity3D Not Working

Tags: android, google-maps, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to embed Google Maps to my Unity Application by following this reference here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#overview. So far, I was able to successfully send the request, like there are no more errors but it does not load the map. It instead loads a big question mark like this below:
[image]

What is the reason for this? Here is the script attached to my Plane btw:

```
IEnumerator _Refresh ()
{
    var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place";
    var qs = "";
    if (!autoLocateCenter) {
        qs += "key=AIzaSyDQ18r-LtVpuo__ms7yl4KW0k9VhMOadgQ";
        qs += "&q=Cebu";
        qs += "&maptype=" + mapType.ToString ().ToLower ();
        qs += "&zoom=" + zoom.ToString ();
    }

    var usingSensor = false;
    #if UNITY_IPHONE
    usingSensor = Input.location.isEnabledByUser && Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Running;
    #endif
    //qs += "&sensor=" + (usingSensor ? "true" : "false");

    foreach (var i in markers) {
        qs += "&markers=" + string.Format ("size:{0}|color:{1}|label:{2}", i.size.ToString ().ToLower (), i.color, i.label);
        foreach (var loc in i.locations) {
            if (loc.address != "")
                qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (loc.address);
            else
                qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0},{1}", loc.latitude, loc.longitude));
        }
    }

    foreach (var i in paths) {
        qs += "&path=" + string.Format ("weight:{0}|color:{1}", i.weight, i.color);
        if(i.fill) qs += "|fillcolor:" + i.fillColor;
        foreach (var loc in i.locations) {
            if (loc.address != "")
                qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (loc.address);
            else
                qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0},{1}", loc.latitude, loc.longitude));
        }
    }

    var req = new WWW (url + "?" + qs);
    yield return req;
    GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture = req.texture;
}
```

Comment: Post your code. How can people help you without your code?

Comment: @Programmer Done sir

Comment: I was not able to re-create your problem because so many variables are missing from the code. I will shoe you a way to Debug your own code. Put `Debug.Log(url + "?" + qs)` before calling `var req = new WWW (url + "?" + qs);`. Copy the link from the Console tab then paste it on a web browser. If it does not work then the way you construct your URL is wrong!

Comment: @Programmer here is the link https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDQ18r-LtVpuo__ms7yl4KW0k9VhMOadgQ&q=Cebu+City&maptype=satellite&zoom=5

This is working right?

Comment: Nope. I get error with that. It should return an image if you are right!

Comment: @Programmer it says "The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe." Is that an error?

Comment: To me yes, you have to find a way to make it return a texture instead of that text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136298/discussion-between-jude-maranga-and-programmer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google uses two different API for their map:

**1**.[Google Maps Embed](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/)

**2**.[Google Map static](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/)

The link you provided is an Embed API. That can only be used on an html page like this:

```
  <iframe src="//www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Harrods,Brompton%20Rd,%20UK
      &zoom=17
      &key=YOUR_API_KEY">
  </iframe>
```

The second method(Static API) returns an image when you make a request. *This is what you should be using*.

The url should be in this format:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?....
```

instead of:

```
https://google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?....
```

So, your link should be something like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIzaSyDQ18r-LtVpuo__ms7yl4KW0k9VhMOadgQ&q=Cebu+City&maptype=satellite&zoom=5&size=640x400.
```

Always try it in the browser before putting it in your code.

**NOTE**:

You have to enable/authorize *Google Map static* in the Google Developers Console. To see more supported parameters, see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/).

Comment: Great you've answered my question! So what I was doing is not possible after all :)

Comment: I wouldn't say "not possible". You would have to build to build your own webkit and Javascript API that will run in Unity. Now, that's where it gets very hard.